# How do i get the hue, saturation and brightness from a UIColor?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uicolor

I want to get the individual values from a UIColor. Unsure how to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIColor comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622217/uicolor-comparison)

Comment: Not sure the question is a duplicate, but @Matt Ball is correct -- the other Q has your answer. Code you want is at http://bravobug.com/news/?p=448

Comment: The aforementioned file is not available anymore :(

Comment: Found the same code in some github-hosted project, made a gist of it: https://gist.github.com/1252197

Answer (score 8):

```
static void RGBtoHSV( float r, float g, float b, float *h, float *s, float *v )
{
    float min, max, delta;
    min = MIN( r, MIN( g, b ));
    max = MAX( r, MAX( g, b ));
    *v = max;               // v
    delta = max - min;
    if( max != 0 )
        *s = delta / max;       // s
    else {
        // r = g = b = 0        // s = 0, v is undefined
        *s = 0;
        *h = -1;
        return;
    }
    if( r == max )
        *h = ( g - b ) / delta;     // between yellow & magenta
    else if( g == max )
        *h = 2 + ( b - r ) / delta; // between cyan & yellow
    else
        *h = 4 + ( r - g ) / delta; // between magenta & cyan
    *h *= 60;               // degrees
    if( *h < 0 )
        *h += 360;
}

static void HSVtoRGB( float *r, float *g, float *b, float h, float s, float v )
{
    int i;
    float f, p, q, t;
    if( s == 0 ) {
        // achromatic (grey)
        *r = *g = *b = v;
        return;
    }
    h /= 60;            // sector 0 to 5
    i = floor( h );
    f = h - i;          // factorial part of h
    p = v * ( 1 - s );
    q = v * ( 1 - s * f );
    t = v * ( 1 - s * ( 1 - f ) );
    switch( i ) {
        case 0:
            *r = v;
            *g = t;
            *b = p;
            break;
        case 1:
            *r = q;
            *g = v;
            *b = p;
            break;
        case 2:
            *r = p;
            *g = v;
            *b = t;
            break;
        case 3:
            *r = p;
            *g = q;
            *b = v;
            break;
        case 4:
            *r = t;
            *g = p;
            *b = v;
            break;
        default:        // case 5:
            *r = v;
            *g = p;
            *b = q;
            break;
    }
}

...

CGFloat r, g, b, a, h, s, v;

const CGFloat *comp = CGColorGetComponents([myUIColor CGColor]);

r = comp[0];
g = comp[1];
b = comp[2];
a = comp[3];

RGBtoHSV(r, g, b, &h, &s, &v);
```

The code above assumes the UIColor is setup in the RGB space (which is typical).  If the color is in another color space it will crash and / or have undefined behavior.

iOS 5.0 has `- (BOOL)getHue:(CGFloat *)hue saturation:(CGFloat *)saturation brightness:(CGFloat *)brightness alpha:(CGFloat *)alpha` which does all this work for you.  But it's not available yet.

Comment: This answer is technically correct, but needs an extra line to make it work with Apple's libraries. At the end of RGB2HSV, add the line: "*h /= 360.0;" -- because Apple specifies H in 0.0..1.0, rather than the Photoshop way which is 0..360

Comment: You should respectively calculate sector this way: `if (h == 1.0) h = 0.0; else h *= 6.0` (instead of dividing by 60) in hsv2rgb() if your H value is in [0.0 ... 1.0]

Answer (score 1):

There's a function called [HSL2RGB()](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GLPaint/Listings/Classes_AppController_m.html) in the GLPaint sample code from Apple that'll do what you want. A comment above the function points you to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSV_color_space) for an explanation of the code, which may help you understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom of Dustin's algorithm, he mentions all UIColor objects in iOS 5 and later now have

```
getHue:saturation:brightness:alpha:
```

This makes it very easy to get the values from a color.  This is definitely the easiest solution now, and most everyone is on iOS 5.

Comment: But for those people who aren't on iOS 5 (yes they still exist), using this method will result in a very timely crash.

Comment: Absolutely - I meant my comment for people who are targeting modern iOS builds. If you can let go of iOS 4 users, it's definitely worth it in maintenance headaches since so many things changed (for the better) in iOS 5.