# Can i find out what color is at a certain point of a UIImage?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get pixel data from a UIImage (Cocoa Touch) or CGImage (Core Graphics)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448125/how-to-get-pixel-data-from-a-uiimage-cocoa-touch-or-cgimage-core-graphics)

Is there a way to look at images in this way? Can somebody point me in the direction of what area to investigate with this?

Comment: Another relevant question (asked by you, no less): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284427/how-do-i-get-the-hue-saturation-and-brightness-from-a-uicolor/5284687

Comment: @Peng: I don't think that one applies: it's about "components of a color", this is "colors of an image".