# How to retrieve HSB from CGColor?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a CGColor in my app and I'd like to get the hue, saturation and brightness values from it. How would i be able to access these?

Comment: I'd take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622217/uicolor-comparison) post talking about UI (and CG) Colors and how to get brightness etc from them.

Answer (score 1):

See Duncan Champney's post to `cocoa-dev` entitled ["Here is code to Convert RGB <-> HSB"](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/198570-here-is-code-to-convert-rgb-hsb.html). There, he gives this code:

```
//------------------
//---header file
#define RETURN_HSV(h, s, v) {HSV.H = h; HSV.S = s; HSV.V = v; return
HSV;}

#define RETURN_RGB(r, g, b) {RGB.R = r; RGB.G = g; RGB.B = b; return
RGB;}

#define UNDEFINED 0

// Theoretically, hue 0 (pure red) is identical to hue 6 in these
transforms. Pure

// red always maps to 6 in this implementation. Therefore UNDEFINED
can be

// defined as 0 in situations where only unsigned numbers are desired.

typedef struct {float R, G, B;} RGBType;

typedef struct {float H, S, V;} HSVType;
//------------------
//--The code
#include <math.h>

HSVType RGB_to_HSV( RGBType RGB )
    {
    // RGB are each on [0, 1]. S and V are returned on [0, 1] and H is
    // returned on [0, 1]. Exception: H is returned UNDEFINED if S==0.
    float R = RGB.R, G = RGB.G, B = RGB.B, v, x, f;
    int i;
    HSVType HSV;
    //x = fminx(R, G, B);
    x = fminf(R, G);
    x = fminf(x, B);
    //v = fmaxf(R, G, B);
    v = fmaxf(R, G);
    v = fmaxf(v, B);
    if(v == x) RETURN_HSV(UNDEFINED, 0, v);
    f = (R == x) ? G - B : ((G == x) ? B - R : R - G);
    i = (R == x) ? 3 : ((G == x) ? 5 : 1);
    RETURN_HSV(((i - f /(v - x))/6), (v - x)/v, v);
    }

RGBType HSV_to_RGB( HSVType HSV )
    {
    // H is given on [0, 1] or UNDEFINED. S and V are given on [0, 1].
    // RGB are each returned on [0, 1].
    float h = HSV.H * 6, s = HSV.S, v = HSV.V, m, n, f;
    int i;
    RGBType RGB;
    if (h == 0) h=.01;
    if(h == UNDEFINED) RETURN_RGB(v, v, v);
    i = floorf(h);
    f = h - i;
    if(!(i & 1)) f = 1 - f; // if i is even
    m = v * (1 - s);
    n = v * (1 - s * f);
    switch (i)
        {
        case 6:
        case 0: RETURN_RGB(v, n, m);
        case 1: RETURN_RGB(n, v, m);
        case 2: RETURN_RGB(m, v, n);
        case 3: RETURN_RGB(m, n, v);
        case 4: RETURN_RGB(n, m, v);
        case 5: RETURN_RGB(v, m, n);
        }
    RETURN_RGB(0, 0, 0);
    }
//------------------
```

Comment: The link to cocoabuilder no longer works - here's the wayback machine's version  https://web.archive.org/web/20120717202441/http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/198570-here-is-code-to-convert-rgb-hsb.html